# scrolltoitematindexpath always returns to the same position

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement adding new portion of information at the top, when user is scrolling to the top (to see chat history) without any jumping like in Telegram, Whatsup and so on

Here is my method

```
private var toItem: NSIndexPath?

private func addMoreCells () {
    if collectionView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        guard let userChatUid = user?.chatUid else { return }
        guard let ownChatUid = UsersManager.sharedInstance.currentChatUID() else { return }
        guard let offset = conversation?.messages.count else { return }


        ConversationsManager.sharedInstance.getConversationsWithMoreMessagesFor(ownChatUid, recipient: userChatUid, offset: offset - 1, successHandler: { [weak weakSelf = self] (conversations) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if let messagesFromServer = conversations.first?.messages, var messages = weakSelf?.conversation?.messages {

                    for message in messagesFromServer {
                        if !messages.contains(message) {
                            messages.append(message)
                        }
                    }

                    messages = messages.sort({$0.time?.compare($1.time!) == .OrderedAscending})

                    weakSelf?.conversation?.messages = messages
                    weakSelf?.collectionView.reloadData()
                    weakSelf?.toItem = NSIndexPath(forItem: (messages.count - messagesFromServer.count), inSection: 0)
                    if let item = weakSelf?.toItem{
                        weakSelf?.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(item, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
                    }

                }
            }

            }, failHandler: { (error) in
                print(error)
        })
    }
}
```

which is launched from

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    addMoreCells()
}
```

First time when I'm scrolling to the top It works as I expect (new portion is added, no jumping. I can see new data and can continue scrolling to the top), but when I continue scrolling to the top and new data are added, it always returns to the position, when first info was added.

But I expect It should return to value `messages.count - messagesFromServer.count`. In xCode I see numbers are changed every time when I'am scrolling, but `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` doesn't work properly

And Every time when I scroll to the top and new data are added, It always returns to first position when first info was added.

Can Anyone know what's problem? Cause I cant find solutions to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem like this:

After `reloadData()` I save `contentSize` of collection view, after that I refresh layout, get new `contentSize` and subtract them to get needed offset to scroll to this place without jumping.

```
weakSelf?.collectionView.reloadData()

guard let previousContentSize = weakSelf?.collectionView.contentSize else { return }

weakSelf?.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
weakSelf?.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.prepareLayout()
weakSelf?.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

guard let newContentSize = weakSelf?.collectionView.contentSize else { return }

print("previous Content Size \(previousContentSize) and new Content Size \(newContentSize)")

let contentOffset = newContentSize.height - previousContentSize.height
weakSelf?.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:  0.0, y: contentOffset), animated: false)
```

I works great and as I would expect.